# how do i exclude a style sheet file from a specific layout in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have an app here, and in my app/assets/stylesheet dir i have all my css file i want to include all the css except mystyle.css, which i don't what my application.html.erb layouts to use. how can i do that? any idea?

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "application:, :media=>"all" %>
```

I tried but it was not working:

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "application:, :media=>"all", :except=>"mystyle.css" %>
```

Comment: using different layouts may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **mystyle.css** reference within your **application.css** file. For example in stylesheets you can require files via the following syntax:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require custom_css_file
*= require mystyle
*/
```

You may want to look at **require_tree**, if you have it, as that will include all CSS files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

only remove "*= require_tree ." from application and other css. See below example.

application.css

```
*
*= require_self
*/
```

pm.css

```
*
*= require_self
*/
```

layout:

pm.html.erb

```
<head>
  <title>Packtup</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "pm", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <title>Packtup</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stub in `application.css`

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= stub mystyle.css
*/
```